# DQL Select Join

Tags: join, doctrine, dql

I'm trying to make a DQL query (doctrine from symfony 2.2) with no success on these entities:

Lesson
Which has several LessonContent
Which are each linked to a User

I want to retrieve all the lessons of a user (should be pretty basic...).

```
SELECT l, lc FROM MyBundle:LessonContent lc 
JOIN lc.lesson l JOIN lc.modifiedBy u 
WHERE lc.creation=1 AND u.id = :userId
```

But this returns the LessonContent entities. If I select from Lesson, I can't JOIN the lessons (which is probably what I should be doing).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out I needed to have a l.content**s** attribute in order to be able to select from lessons and then JOIN on the rest.

Entity:

```
 /**
 * @var ArrayCollection $contentHistory
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AAA\CoreBundle\Entity\LessonContent", mappedBy="lesson", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"lastModified" = "DESC"})
 */
private $contentHistory;
```

Query:

```
SELECT l FROM AAACoreBundle:Lesson l JOIN l.contentHistory lc JOIN lc.modifiedBy u WHERE lc.creation=1 AND u.id = :userId GROUP BY l
```

And with that it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

The main table you query from is what doctrine gives you back as the main objects, so the following should work (assuming l.content points to the LessonContent association):

```
SELECT l, lc FROM MyBundle:Lesson l
JOIN l.content lc
JOIN lc.modifiedBy u
WHERE lc.creation=1 AND u.id = :userId
```